# Node express socketio listening and console logging any data recieved

Tags: html, node.js, socket.io

can any body show me a simple node express server that opens up a listening socket and console log any data it receives i need this to test a HTML script i am building with socketio involved.

i will be sending data using a text box array and i just want the node server to console log everything received

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code but you will have to install *ejs* module using `npm install ejs` to render your html pages to client. And you will have to create a folder named *views* in the same directory where your app.js is, and you'll put your html files in this folder.

**Server side: app.js**

```
var express = require('express')
, http = require('http')
,  app = express();
app.configure(function () {
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 456);
app.engine('.html', ejs.__express);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'html');
});
var server = http.createServer(app);
io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('someEvent', function(data){
    console.log(data.prop1 + " " + data.prop2);
  });
});
```

**Client side: index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='socket.io/socket.io.js'></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:456');
</script>
//emit this event when your function executes
socket.emit('someEvent', {prop1: 'value1', prop2: 'value2'});
```

Hope this might help

Comment: i have tried this alot with c9.io but cannot get it to work at all